# Postpone Quartz job with a interval time when do not match run-time condition, but still keep old scheduler?

Tags: c#, quartz

I am finding a solution to `Quartz job`.

I have a Quartz job is executed by my scheduler which is define as Cron Expression. However, in this job, I have to check a run-time condition. If it doesn't match, the job will delay firing about 2 hours, then keep the old scheduler as normal.

Is it possible?

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    if (_isMaintenanceSystem)
    {
        // Delay job
        // When delay, job fires and keep old scheduler as normal.
    }

    SendMail(_emailSetting, fileAttachment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** You can complete by doing 2 steps:

*Step 1. Modify your main job like this*

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    if (_isMaintenanceSystem)
    {
        _logger.Info($"Start UM checking");
        context.Scheduler.PauseJob(context.Trigger.JobKey);
        
        // You would schedule a task named CheckUMJob
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<CheckUMJob>()
            .WithIdentity("CheckUMJob", "CheckUMJob_schedule")
            .Build();
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("CheckUMJob", "CheckUMJob_schedule")
            .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatMinutelyForever(15))
            .StartNow()
            .Build();
        context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
     }

    // Do your task here as normally
    SendMail(_emailSetting, fileAttachment);
}
```

*Step 2. Create a new `CheckUMJob` like this*

```
public class CheckUMJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CheckUMJob(ILogger loggere)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        if (!_isMaintenanceSystem)
        {
            _logger.Info("End of maintenance time. Resume the main job");

            context.Scheduler.DeleteJob(context.Trigger.JobKey);
            context.Scheduler.ResumeAll();
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, it will follow by the `Single Responsibility Principle`. It means do one thing.